# NITE installation problems

Tags: installation, openni

I have already installed OpenNI and SensorKinect, but when I try to install NITE, it fails halfway through. This is the output. What could be the problem?

I also have an earlier version of NITE installed. Would it be compatible with the newer version of OpenNI if this version of NITE will not install?

Installing NITE

---

Copying shared libraries... OK

Copying includes... OK

Installing java bindings... OK

Installing module 'Features_1_3_0'...

Registering module 'libXnVFeatures_1_3_0.so'... OK

Installing module 'Features_1_3_1'...

Registering module 'libXnVFeatures_1_3_1.so'... OK

Installing module 'Features_1_4_1'...

Registering module 'libXnVFeatures_1_4_1.so'... OK

Installing module 'Features_1_4_2'...

Registering module 'libXnVFeatures_1_4_2.so'... Failed: Error!

Answer (score 2):

1. install unstable OpenNi (OpenNi Binaries) [download](http://www.openni.org/Downloads/OpenNIModules.aspx)
2. Install Sensor [download](https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect/tree/unstable/Bin)
3. Install unstable NITE [download](http://www.openni.org/Downloads/OpenNIModules.aspx)
4. Install avin2 / SensorKinect  [download](https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect)

Follow step by step. At present I have installed openNi and Kinect and workd fine. After that you are ready for run the samples in  your OpenNi folder. Happy code !

Comment: hi I want to install OpenNi and the download links you mentioned are not working. Are there any alternative links ?